# Two way communication with Reactive Extensions

Tags: c#, .net, system.reactive, reactive-programming

Let's imagine I have a hot observable that is a source of weather events. This source is a socket connection to a remote server that provides information about the weather in my current location.

That remote server can also send me events about other related topics as traffic, extreme weather warnings, etc... if I send a command to indicate this desire.

How can I model this with Reactive Extensions without creating coupling between observable and observer?

The idea is that when I subscribe `ExtremeWeatherWarnings` (observer) to my `WeatherServerConnection` (observable), somehow the first issue some commands to the second, so it enables the subscription.

I have tried to implement an special interface in the observer, that tells the observable the commands it needs to execute in subscription and unsubscription, but it does not work in the moment I put a `Where` in the middle because LINQ RX is wrapping the observable, and that wrapper does not implement any interface.

I can also require an instance of the `WeatherServerConnection` object on the `ExtremeWeatherWarnings` constructor, but that will create coupling and I would like to avoid that.

Cheers.

Comment: Looks like you need something similar to ISubject. Check out [Ping-Pong example](http://rxwiki.wikidot.com/101samples#toc44)

Comment: That example is very naive. I need that `ExtremeWeatherWarnings` populate other kind of things for its consumers. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If your observables is designed to send generic messages, and your observer is design to translate them, you also need a way of indicating to the producer what kinds of messages you're interested in.

One way to do this is "requesting an observable".

```
ObservableWeatherSource GetNotifications(WeatherWarnings warningTypes, string location);
```

Another way might be to lazily indicate what notifications you're interested in.

```
ObservableWeatherSource source = GetWeatherSource();

source
    .Where(x => x.WeatherWarningType === WeatherWarnings.Rain)
    .Subscribe(new WeatherObserver());

source.ExpressInterestIn(WeatherWarnings.Rain, "San Francisco");
```

Or, possibly, you might be interested in writing a specialized query language for weather. You could probably do this through the `IQbservable` and a query provider, but I have little knowledge of this area of Rx.

Comment: And how does ´ExtremeWeatherWarnings´ communicates with ´WeatherServerConnection´ ?

Comment: Apologies. I switched around some nouns. I've updated the example.

Comment: I will note, however, that an `Observer` *never* communicates anything to the `Observable`. That would break the pattern. That being said, there could potentially be exceptions to this rule when dealing with back pressure, but that is not the issue at hand here. You most certainly need some other channel by which to communicate what you need out of the observable.

Comment: In your example, `ObservableWeatherSource` is already aware of `WeatherWarnings.Rain`, what means that if in the future there are new warnings, I have to modify also `ObservableWeatherSource`, and that is what I want to avoid. The idea is good though.

Comment: The Observer/Observable pattern is not for bi-directional communication. You could create a custom push-based monad for your uses, but that's going to be much more complicated than simply creating a secondary avenue for instruction sets. What do you hope to accomplish by communicating bi-directionally?

Answer (score 1):

It all depends on how you think of your observables.

If it's a stream of events independent of the observers, you can just expose the observable to anyone that want's to subscribe to.

That was the approach I followed on my [reactive GeoCoordinateWatcher](http://developer.nokia.com/community/wiki/Implementing_GeoCordinateWatcher_as_a_Reactive_Service). The wrapped [GeoCoordinateWatcher class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/System.Device.Location.GeoCoordinateWatcher.aspx) will generate events independent of the subscription.

For the [reactive Geolocator](http://developer.nokia.com/community/wiki/Exposing_the_Geolocator_as_a_Reactive_Service) I chose to follow the same approach. But because the [Geolocator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windowsphone/develop/windows.devices.geolocation.geolocator.aspx) needs parameterization to produce events, I could have chosen to implement an observable factory.

The bottom line is (as @Christopher said) that you send commands to something that exposes an observable and not to the observale itself.

You migth do something like sending commands to the observable by applying **Rx** operators. If those filters are to be applied remotely, you can implement (as @Christopher said) an [IQbservale](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/hh229328.aspx) instead.